# How can I know where the request.user from in Django View?

Tags: python, django

How can I know where the request.user from ?

I have a TestRequestUserAPIView:

```
class TestRequestUserAPIView(View):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        result = super(TestRequestUserAPIView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return result

    def get(self, request):
        user = request.user  # this line I get the user (who access the API)
        return HttpResponse("ok")
```

When it execute this line `user = request.user`.
I can get the request `user`(who request this API).

I want to know how the user generate in request, why I request this API in browser like Chrome, I the request will have the user property?

Does it through the cookie ? or some token (In my test project, I logined. But I did not put the token to the request when access the API, still get the user in backend reqest.user)?

---

**EDIT -1**

I have django `build-in` auth, and `rest-auth` in my project:

The bellow auth are in my INSTALLED_APPS:

```
'django.contrib.auth',
'rest_auth',
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'rest_auth.registration',
```

I also want to know the frontend pass what to backend for identity the user, does it use cookie? or token? I use rest-auth to generate a token when login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using [Django's built-in authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/) - i.e. you have the `django.contrib.auth` included in your settings installed apps.

Middlewares get a chance to intercept the `request` before any of your views receive it.
This `request.user` attribute is set by Django's auth middleware, [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/746caf3ef821dbf7588797cb2600fa81b9df9d1d/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py#L79-L83):

```
class RemoteUserMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    """
    Middleware for utilizing Web-server-provided authentication.
    If request.user is not authenticated, then this middleware attempts to
    authenticate the username passed in the ``REMOTE_USER`` request header.
    If authentication is successful, the user is automatically logged in to
    persist the user in the session.
    The header used is configurable and defaults to ``REMOTE_USER``.  Subclass
    this class and change the ``header`` attribute if you need to use a
    different header.
    """
    ...
    def process_request(self, request):
        ...
        # We are seeing this user for the first time in this session, attempt
        # to authenticate the user.
        user = auth.authenticate(request, remote_user=username)
        if user:
            # User is valid.  Set request.user and persist user in the session
            # by logging the user in.
            request.user = user
            auth.login(request, user)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, can I debug your post code in my project?

Comment: Yes, you can, just find the `django/contrib/auth/middleware.py` file in your local installation and set a breakpoint in there.

Comment: To be honest,  I also want to know the frontend pass what to backend for identity the user, does it use cookie? or token? I use rest-auth to generate a token when login.

Comment: It uses both (a session token in the cookies).

Answer (score 0):

In [Authentication in web requests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests) we read a very short explanation

> Django uses sessions and middleware to hook the authentication system into request objects. These provide a request.user attribute on every request which represents the current user. If the current user has not logged in, this attribute will be set to an instance of AnonymousUser, otherwise it will be an instance of User.

For most that information will suffice. Yet, if one wants to understand better what happens under the hood, let’s try to login a user and see what happens.
To log a user in, from a view, we use [`login()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login). For example, if one [tests in this system by Creative Tim](https://www.creative-tim.com/live/material-dashboard-django),

One sends a `POST` request with the data:

```
username:test
password:ApS12_ZZs8
```

If login is successful, `login()` saves the user’s ID in the session using Django’s session framework, [which is entirely, and solely, cookie-based,](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/sessions/#session-ids-in-urls) (by default, Django [stores sessions in your database, in a `django_session` table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/sessions/#configuring-the-session-engine)), and we’ll get back a cookie in the request header

```
cookie: sessionid=53u40ngk6puzfru3gl7p5zhbx0yrkoo3
```

[image]

So, what is that `sessionid` we are getting? It's the `session_key` in the `django_session` table. The table looks like the following

[image]

```
   Column        |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default
----------------------+--------------------------+---------------+--------------+-------------
session_key   | character varying(40)          |                 | not null |
session_data | text                                         |                 | not null |
expire_date    | timestamp with time zone  |                | not null |
```

So, knowing the `session_key` it’s possible to know the `session_data`. It’s in `session_data` that when a user logs in, [the user’s ID and the backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#selecting-the-authentication-backend) that was used for authentication are saved as an encoded dictionary. This allows the same [authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#authentication-backends) to fetch the user’s details on a future request.

Since [authentication sources are cached on a per-session basis](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends), if one changes `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` (one can even [create a custom one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend)) one will need to clear out session data to force users to re-authenticate using different methods (`Session.objects.all().delete()`).

By default, [Django only saves to the session database when the session has been modified](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved) – that is if any of its dictionary values have been assigned or deleted.

Then, when one calls [`logout()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.logout), the session data for the current request is completely cleaned out. In other words, one still gets a `cookie: sessionid=...` in the header, except that the `session_data` linked with that `session_key` won’t have the `_auth_user_id` like before.

Which is great but that still doesn’t explain how Django knows the user making the request. Looking back at the beginning of the answer, there’s a quote saying `Django uses sessions and middleware to hook the authentication system into request objects.`. We’ve covered the sessions, so that must be the part handled by Middleware. One is correct if one assumes that. More specifically, Django’s auth middleware sets the `request.user` attribute [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py#L80), as noted by [wim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47544680/7109869), and that’s done essentially by extracting the user and the authentication backend from the session.

---

**Notes:**

- [As per the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/sessions/#clearing-the-session-store), it’s recommended to call `clearsessions` on a regular basis to purge expired sessions, for example as a daily cron job.